# run function in function

Tags: function, octave

I'm new to Octave and I've a script that work in matlab that have following structure  :

```
function []=myFunctionName()
...
a='path';
b=2;
c=5
d='x';
[x,y]=lecFunc(a,b,c,d);
plot(x,y);
...
function [k,t]=lecFunc(pt, nF, nS, val)

....

fid=fopen(pt,'r');
k=fread(fid,[1,N],'real*4');fclose(fid);
t=linspace(tmin,tmax,nt);

etc ...
```

And I get the error :

```
error: 'lecFunc' undefined near line 141 column 10
```

I couldn't understand why... I try to seprate the functions with `endfunction` and also put the function `lecFunc` at the top, but it still not work...

Could someone help me to understand this difference between matlab and octave ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: This should work. The issue might be where you elided code using "....". Could you instead of paraphrasing please create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?  Remove all the code from your function, and see what the minimum amount of code is that you need to reproduce this error. You will likely find your answer yourself this way, but if not, post the MCVE.

Comment: How have you called your file with the above pseudocode and how do you call it? If you work with Octave it's important to understand, that there is a difference between function files and script files.

Comment: I try `run(myFile.m)` with octave... the file should have the same name as the main function ?

Answer (score 1):

You use `lecFunc` in `myFunctionName`. Try to define `lecFunc` before defining `myFunctionName`

Comment: yes I tried, but it did not solve the problem...